# In Linux, schedule task to Hour, minute, second precision

Tags: linux, task, schedule, seconds

I just want to run a shell scrip at say this exact time "16:22:36". utilities like "at" are useless since they don't have "seconds". "sleep" does not work since the loop is ending 8 hours ahead of time for some reason :s , I have searched all over google and couldn't find any tools. so  a huge Os like Linux doesn't have a proper task scheduler?

Answer (score 10):

The standard `cron` lacks second precision scheduling because

1. Unix server administration traditionally rarely needed one-second precision
2. It might be used in such a disturbing way for a multi-user system like "Run this task every second"

However with the help of `sleep(1)` from GNU Coreutils suite, you can achieve true second precision job scheduling.

Example: wait for 12:14:05 and 12:14:10

```
$ crontab -l
(snip...)
14 12 * * * sleep 5; date > /tmp/plain.txt
14 12 * * * while [ "1410" -gt "$(date +\%M\%S)" ]; do /bin/sleep 0.1; done; date > /tmp/while.txt
```

(wait for a while...)

```
$ ls -l --time-style=full-iso /tmp/*.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nodakai nodakai 43 2014-02-22 12:14:06.236151567 +0800 /tmp/plain.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nodakai nodakai 43 2014-02-22 12:14:10.007600677 +0800 /tmp/while.txt
```

As you see from the 1st version, `14 12` in `crontab` does not guarantee `12:14:00` sharp.  The 2nd version uses `while` loop and sub-second `sleep(1)` to achieve sub-second precision.

**Note that, unless you use NTP to synchronize your machine clock to time servers, it is meaningless to talk about second precision job scheduling.**

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `crontab` entry for the hour and minute with a sleep of 36 seconds

```
22 16 * * * sleep 36; shell_script.sh
```

Comment: so Linux really doesn't have a task scheduler with seconds built in? why? how? i mean...!!!

Comment: You assumed `22 16` will run at 16:22:00 sharp but unfortunately it will necessarily not.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has a wonderful task scheduler, called `crontab`. There is a wealth of info about it on the web. As a simple "this is what it does and how to use it" though: http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/ - Should get you started.

Comment: Except that the minimum timeframe in cron is 1 minute...

Comment: Granted, but as @Vimsha points out, there are ways around that. It's still the best option imho.

Comment: Right, but just wanted to point it out since there was no mention of sleep in the article you linked to.

Comment: Because each user has his/her own `crontab` file, `sudo` is not necessary unless you want to run the command itself with root privilege.